# Why is the value of the 'id' column of the database showing null?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6.I have created a table called `'student'`, where the value increment of the `'id'` column is supposed to happen but is not happening.

This is my migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStudentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->bigInteger('phone');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('students');
    }
}
```

In my students table:

[image]

My StudentController file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;
class StudentController extends Controller
{
   public function student()
   {
        return view('student.create');
   }


   public function index()
   {
        $student = Student::all();
        return view('student.index', compact('student'));
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {
     $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:50|min:5',
        'phone' => 'required|unique:students|max:12min:9',
        'email' => 'required|unique:students',
         ]);


    $student = new Student;
    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->email = $request->email;
    $student->phone = $request->phone;
    $student->save();
    $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Data Insert Done!', 
            'alert-type' => 'success'
            );

            return Redirect()->route('all.category')->with($notification);

    // DB::table('student')->insert($data)
   // return response()->json($student);

   }


   public function ViewStudent()
   {
        
   }

   
}
```

Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
       protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'phone',
    ];
}
```

Comment: you seem to be inserting a null value into `id`, if you are using an implementation like `$students->id = $someVar ` remove it

Comment: @Ainz-sama Sir, In my implementation I don't use like`$students->id = $someVar` this expression.

Comment: Check your table structure by `SHOW CREATE TABLE students;` Is `id` column have `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Show your controller

Comment: @Sobir sir, Update my code.

Comment: please upload your model code too

Comment: @Ainz-sama sir, Update my code.

Comment: Please see answer for sample model code.

Comment: Use `$table->bigIncrements('id');` in migration

Comment: Simply just take out `‘id‘` from fillable and it will work as expected.

Comment: btw a phone number is not an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that you are working with a database whose schema was set for the `students` table either manually (not through migration, but, for example, by executing an SQL query where auto-increment was not set), or after applying the migration, the auto-increment was removed.

Because your migration code is written correctly according to the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns) for the method `increments(string $attribute)`:

[image]

I see two solutions here:

1. change a table column via SQL query so that it matches the description in the migration

`ALTER TABLE students CHANGE id id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;`

or the same using phpmyadmin or IDE tools;

2. generate a schema using your migration (`php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/..._create_students_table.php`), but for this preliminarily you need to save the students table data, for example, to a dump.

Since you are using *phpmyadmin*, look at the settings for the `id` attribute in the `students` table.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib, so you can accept my answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is if you did something like this in your model:

```
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
```

If so then it should be set to true or removed entirely.

Second, make sure your `id` is guarded in your model like so:

```
/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

This way you avoid mass assignments.

Comment: You should only guard it where you are not using explicit fillable list, just one or the other - but not both

Comment: We are not sure how he is filling his data so am ruling the obvious out.

Comment: You're not wrong, I'm just stating that one should not be using guarded if the model is already declared with a fillable list ;-)

Comment: @Qirel Sir,I am using fillable.

Comment: @Humayun Quick question, hope you didn't include `id` in fillable? If your answer is NO then something is wrong and I would suggest updating to the most recent version of Laravel 6 or if possible migrate to 7.

Comment: The problem is solved, thank you sir for helping me.

Comment: Am still bugged out by your problem can you please share what your solution was? Cos I said a bunch of things and am not sure which helped you...lol

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your controller code, I assume the error lies somewhere in the line where you grab an instance of your student model

Change

```
 $student = new Student;
```

To

```
  $student = new Student();
```

You need a new instance of a specific model in order to insert a new id, please post your current model code also.

Sample model code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_bar_code', 'product_name', 'product_image', 'product_price'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
}
```

Maybe something is wrong with the way you have written your model code.

Comment: the problem is sovled,thank you sir for helping me.

Comment: `new Student;` is the same as `new Student();`